# Connect Windows Azure websites with Windows Azure virtual machines

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

There is a recent article in the Windows Azure blog about connecting Windows Azure websites with a Windows Azure virtual machine

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/01/24/wordpress-with-memcached-on-azure-websites.aspx

How do you allow connections only form Windows Azure Websites instances without opening a port to the rest of the internet?

Comment: Wait, do your VM will host only memcached for your web site??

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio suppose that I need some services form the VM that are not available in the Windows Azure websites. It could be anything a special database like redis, memcache, a graph database, etc

Comment: Ok, I asked because there's Windows Azure Cache (Preview) that you can use to store objects, state / output page of your aspnet pages.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the IP range for the datacenter the web site is in to the ACL on the IaaS VM endpoint. Unfortunately this doesn't restrict traffic from other applications in that same datacenter.

Ideally, there would be some way to leverage Azure Virtual Network to create a trust relationship between the Web Site and IaaS VM much like you can with PaaS Cloud Services. But at this time this isn't available.

Comment: How do I know the IP range of the Windows Azure websites datacenter?

Comment: We publish the list (which is also updated periodically). http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653